# some confusion in order square.

Tags: general-topology

```
find the closure of these sets on the ordered square
```

$$A = \{(1/n)\times 0 | n\in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$$

i was thinking about this question and i found the answer  here

[Finding the closure of some subsets of the ordered square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923358/finding-the-closure-of-some-subsets-of-the-ordered-square)

As  im unot understanding this answer as mark in red colour

[image]

Pliz help me and thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make a sketch as suggested in the text? If so, what did it look like?

Comment: @AndreasBlass..i was trying  to draw,,but could not understand how can i sketch ?   as i can draw suppose if a=0, b=1/3 and C= 1/2 and d = 1  as  i can locate this point on XY coordinate

Comment: Using specific values like $\frac13$ and $\frac12$ was a good idea. Now check a few specific points to see whether they're in $(u,v)$, i.e., whether they're between $\langle0,\frac13\rangle$ and $\langle\frac12,1\rangle$. I suggest checking a few points on the left edge (i.e., points with first coordinate $0$), a few points with first coordinate $\frac12$, a few points in between (maybe first coordinates $\frac17$ or $\frac13$) and a few points with first coordinate beyond $\frac12$ (maybe $\frac34$). That should give you a pretty good idea of the picture and help you fill in the proof.

Comment: The def'n of A doe not make grammatical sense. Please edit.

Comment: im not getting@DanielWainfleet  what u want to say ????